# Set Visibility of loaded layers to false except the checked one in Openlayers 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

All layers were WMS from GeoServer service. I want to set the visibility of the layer only if it is checked and it is also loaded at the same time when checked.

This is my HTML markup:

```
...
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="2year" value="2year" onclick="toggleStatic(this);">2-Year Rainfall
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="5year" value="5year" onclick="toggleStatic(this);">5-Year Rainfall
    </label>
</div>
...
```

I have created a function but it's not good and can't identify what layers are currently loaded.

Sample on loading map:

```
$("#5year").one("click", function() {
    $(this).is(":checked");
    fiveCBR = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "5-Year Flood Hazard Map CBR", "http://10.0.0.23:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms",
                {
                    srs: 'EPSG:32651',
                    layers: 'cite:evidensapp_cbrfiveyear',
                    format:'image/png8',
                    //gridSet: 'EPSG:4326',
                    transparent: true
                },
                //{'displayInLayerSwitcher':false},
                {
                    singleTile: false, 
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    ratio: 1                    
                }           
         );
    map.addLayer(fiveCBR);
});
```

And this is the function for setting the visibility of the layer:

```
function toggleStatic(e){
    if(e.value == '5year'){
        floodMapCBR.setVisibility(false);
        seniang2014.setVisibility(false);
        twoCBR.setVisibility(false);
        fiveCBR.setVisibility(e.checked);
        tenCBR.setVisibility(false);
        twentyfiveCBR.setVisibility(false);
        fiftyCBR.setVisibility(false);
        hundredCBR.setVisibility(false);
    }
...
```

The problem is I can't identify what layers have been already loaded, so it returns an error:

> Cannot read property 'setVisibility' of undefined

To sum it up, **I want to set all the loaded layers' visibility to false except the checked one.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to figure this out, with the same HTML markup use these functions:

```
function toggleStatic(e) {
    var layers = map.getLayersByName(e.value);
    var mLayers = map.layers;
    for (var a = 0; a < mLayers.length; a++) {
        if(mLayers[a].CLASS_NAME == "OpenLayers.Layer.WMS"){
            var str =  mLayers[a].name;
            if(str == e.value){
                if(layers.length === 1) {
                    layers[0].setVisibility(true);
                }
            }
            else{
                hideLayer(str);
            }
        }
    }

}

function hideLayer(layerName) {
    var layers = map.getLayersByName(layerName);
    if(layers.length === 1) {
        layers[0].setVisibility(false);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error');
    }
}
```